# LuaJIT require module error

Tags: lua, luajit

```
require "utils.lua"
stdin:1: module 'utils.lua' not found:
        no field package.preload['utils.lua']
        no file 'D:\blizzard\Projects\Lua'
        no file '.\utils\lua.dll'
        no file 'D:\blizzard\Projects\Lua\utils\lua.dll'
        no file 'D:\blizzard\Projects\Lua\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\utils.dll'
        no file 'D:\blizzard\Projects\Lua\utils.dll'
        no file 'D:\blizzard\Projects\Lua\loadall.dll'
```

Why LuaJIT searches for .dll instead of .lua and how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should `require utils` (ditch the .lua) , and utils.lua should be on your `package.path` variable, or passed as the LUA_PATH environment variable.

More info in the Lua Reference Manual about [package.loaders](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders), [require()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) and [package.path](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.path)

Comment: "and utils . lus should be ... passed as the LUA_PATH". I haven't understood this. Directory where I placed utils.lua is in the LUA_PATH env. variable and I omitted ".lua" but this doesn't help.

Comment: utils.lua. Sorry typo. So your package.path variable contains a lot of directories where Lua looks for libraries. utils.lua should be in one of them.

Comment: OK, I changed LUA_PATH to D:\blizzard\Projects\Lua\?.lua and it worked.

Comment: How do I make lua search for .\file.lua instead of .\file.dll? I just want to require some files in my project directory without having to set LUA_PATH each time.

Comment: you can use `package.path=package.path..'./?.lua;'` before using `require`. Also note the difference between package.path and package.cpath (and LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH). Ther former concerns Lua files, while the latter concerns compiled C libraries.